# Uploading Video File to AZURE BLOB STORAGE in NODEJS

Tags: node.js, azure, blob

I am new to uploading files to blob storage and I need help for uploading video file to azure blob storage in nodejs. I have done a bit of code for this service.

here is my service code snippet

```
 uploadCourseVideo.post(multipartMiddleware, function (req, res) {
    var dataStream;
    console.log(req.body, req.files);
fs.readFile(req.files.file.path, function (err, dataStream) {
            var blobSvc = azure.createBlobService('ariasuniversity', 'account key');
            blobSvc.createContainerIfNotExists('elmsvideos', function (error, result, response) {
                if (!error) {
                    // Container exists and is private
                    blobSvc.createBlockBlobFromStream('elmsvideos', 'myblob', dataStream, dataStream.length, function (error, result, response) {
                        if (!error) {
                            // file uploaded
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
});`
```

The error which I am getting is of Stream.pause() is not a function.[image: THe Error Image]

Please Help me out. Thanks

Comment: 2 things: 1) You included your account key in the question. Even though I edited the question and removed the key but anybody can go in edit history and see the key. **I request you to change your account key immediately**. 2) Please paste error message as text instead of an image. It makes things easier that way.

Comment: @GauravMantri Oka Bro Thanx For the Security Concern. I am changing it right now.

Answer (score 1):

You used `fs.readfile()` function which wouldn't return a stream, thus raising your issue.
You could use `fs.createReadStream()` function instead, and then you can use [`createWriteStreamToBlockBlob`](http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/BlobService.html#createWriteStreamToBlockBlob) to provide a stream to write to a block blob.

```
var readStream = fs.createReadStream(req.files.file.path);

var blobSvc = azure.createBlobService('ariasuniversity', 'account key');
blobSvc.createContainerIfNotExists('elmsvideos', function (error, result, response) {
    if (!error) {
        // Container exists and is private
        readStream.pipe(blobSvc.createWriteStreamToBlockBlob('elmsvideos', 'myblob', function (error, result, response) {
            if(!error) {
                // file uploaded
            }
        }));

    }
});
```